# MathML's msqrt not tall enough for fraction

Tags: html, css, mathml

I am new to MathML so please bear with me. I created the following equation:

```
<math>
  <msqrt>
    <mfrac>
      <mi> A </mi>
      <mi> B </mi>
    </mfrac>
  </msqrt>
</math>
```

But the results show the sqrt only over "A". I want it to be taller so it is over A and B.

I tried playing around with changing the css file, like margins and padding, but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Your code works fine for me when I use it inside the MathML MDN playground so there is something else wrong with your setup so we need more information about your  setup. e.g. font, OS/browser, how you have MathML loaded.

Comment: I have to apologize. After reading your comment,  I just realized I was using a style sheet which had "math {font-family: Calibri;}". When I removed this, the problem went away. I also found that even with the css, it worked ok in Firefox, but not in Chrome. I am new to posting in stackoverflow, so if I am doing anything wrong with how I comment. please let me know. I wanted to do an update or reply but there was no button for it.